# Returning the sum of a column without using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following sql...

```
declare @parent table (id int, description varchar(50))
declare @child table (parentid int, amount money)

insert into @parent(id, description) values (1, 'test')

insert into @child(parentid, amount) values (1, 3)
insert into @child(parentid, amount) values (1, 3)

select p.*,
       sum(c.amount) as amount
    from @parent p         
        inner join @child c on c.parentid = p.id
```

Generates the following error...

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Column '@parent.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

This fixes it...

```
select p.*,
       sum(c.amount) as amount
    from @parent p         
        inner join @child c on c.parentid = p.id
    group by p.id,
             p.description
```

How do I change it so the query returns the sum of the child records, but without using the group by expression?  Maybe a subquery of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express this as:

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(c.amount) as amount
        from @child c 
        where c.parentid = p.id
       ) as child_amount
from @parent p;
```

However, this is not exactly equivalent, because it include parents with no children.  One solution is:

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(c.amount) as amount
        from @child c 
        where c.parentid = p.id
       ) as child_amount
from @parent p
where exists (select 1 from @child c where c.parentid = p.id);
```

That said, you can also use `apply`:

```
select p.*, c.amount 
from @parent p cross apply
     (select sum(c.amount) as amount 
      from @child c 
      where c.parentid = p.id
     ) c;
```

`cross apply` filters out non-matches (`outer apply` keeps them).

Answer (score 2):

You can use *window* function :

```
select distinct p.*, sum(c.amount) over (partition by p.id) as amount
from @parent p inner join 
     @child c 
     on c.parentid = p.id;
```

You can also use `apply` :

```
select distinct p.*, c.amount 
from @parent p cross apply
     (select sum(c.amount) as amount 
      from @child c 
      where c.parentid = p.id
     ) c;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works, but it returns 2 rows.  How can it be changed to only return a single row?

Comment: @JohnLivermore. . . Use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . No `distinct` is needed for `cross apply`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . Sample data have a duplicate record. & `@parent` also have a duplicate record.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . `@parent` doesn't have any duplicates in the question, at least as it is now written.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . When i answered. I think it was.

Answer (score 1):

window aggregates:

```
select p.*,
       sum(c.amount) over(partition by p.id) as amountperparent,
       sum(c.amount) over() as amountofallchildren
    from @parent p         
        inner join @child c on c.parentid = p.id;
```

--subquery

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(c.amount) from @child as c where c.parentid = p.id) as amountperparent,
       (select sum(c.amount) from @child as c ) as amountofallchildren
    from @parent p ;
```

--derived aggregation

```
select p.*, c.amountperparent
from @parent p       
join
(
    select parentid, sum(amount) as amountperparent
    from @child
    group by parentid
) as c on p.id = c.parentid;
```